# Are references across .o files resolved when building a static library?

Tags: c, linker

For example, let's say I build a library a.lib that has two files: foo.c and bar.c. foo.c calls a function `void bar()` defined in bar.c.

Now let's say I have an executable that I'm going to create that has two files: main.c and bar.c. This bar.c also has `void bar()` defined, but with a different implementation.

When I link the executable with a.lib, which `void bar()` will be called by the executable?

Comment: please post your code and what you try to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume that:

1. The library is `libfoobar.a` (or `libfoobar.lib`) and is in directory `./lib`.
2. The library file `foo.c` defines `foo()` and `foo()` calls `bar()`.
3. The library file `bar.c` defines `bar()`.
4. The library source files are not in the current directory.
5. The program file `bar.c` also defines `bar()` — a different implementation.
6. The program file `main.c` calls both `foo()` and `bar()`.
7. Your linking command line looks like:

   ```
   cc -o program main.o bar.o -L ./lib -lfoobar
   ```

Then:

- The program will contain the `bar()` from the program file `bar.c` (because that was explicitly included on the command line, ahead of the library).
- The program will contain the `foo()` from the library file `foo.c`, but the `bar()` that it calls will be the one from the program file `bar.c`, not the one from the library.

If there are more symbols involved, so that the library `foo.c` calls functions which are only available in the library `bar.c` (the program `bar.c` does not implement all those functions), then the linking will fail because the program contains the program's `bar.c` (unconditionally), but it also needs the library's `bar.c`, but that gives you a double definition of the function `bar()` — which is an error.

The twists and turns can get serious.  Simple rule of thumb — don't do it.  That is, don't make the program's `bar.c` provide the symbol that is also available in the library's `bar.c`.  If you must and there are other entry points involved, then you have to work a lot harder.

Don't put libraries before object files; then you'll fail with `bar()` doubly defined.  Libraries go after object files in the link list.  You do need to get multiple (static) libraries in the correct order, though.  Or use special options to make the loader rescan libraries, etc.